# Retrieve text using DomDocument, but remove inner h1 tag

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have some html where I'm attempting to retrieve the text but not with the `<h1>` tag content.

```
$html = '<div class="mytext">   
           <h1>Title of document</h1>   
           This is the text that I want, without the title.
         </div>';

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xp->query('//div[@class="mytext"]') as $node) {
  $description = $node->nodeValue;
  echo $description; 
}
```

End result should be: `This is the text that I want, without the title.`

Currently it's: `Title of document This is the text that I want, without the title`

How can I just get the text without the h1 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($xp->query('//div[@class="mytext"]/text()[normalize-space()]') as $node) {
   $description = $node->nodeValue;
   echo $description; 
}
```